# Change/Hide the pen width for line shape file based on rule in QGIS

Tags: qgis, print-composer, rule-based

I have line shapefile, in which I have a condition to display line's width based on a rule as shown in the image below. But in this case I was not able to define line width to `0`, it is taking `hairline` as minimum by default. Is there any other way to hide the other features in print-composer, so that I can print only selected features?

[image]

**Basically I need to print only the green line with hidden black lines:**

[image]

Comment: Full transparency ?

Comment: yes full Transparency. But below answer has solved my concern. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can use the Data Defined Override in Colour to define a full opacity for the not selected lines.

[image]

Here, click in Edit and use this expression

```
case 
when 
$id  =  @atlas_featureid then '0,0,0,255'
else '0,0,0,0'
end
```

This will solve your problem.

You can also change the RGB colour in the first line to suite your preferences.

[image]

Comment: Yes it has worked fine now. Before i was using the below code 
----------
case 
when 
$id  =  @atlas_featureid then color_rgb(0,0,255)
else color_rgb(0,0,0)
end
-----------
Thanks